# XML transformation exception

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I receive the following exception when transforming an XML file to pdf.
The error seems specific to Java

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: 
Could not load the translet class 'GregorSamsa'.
```

Cannot understand the reason.
Any helpful suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=Could+not+load+the+translet+class) knows a lot about error messages. This one *could* be a known bug.

Comment: If @Andreas_D's comment doesn't lead to a solution (see json's final comment on at http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5056688), it would be helpful for us to know a lot more about the context. What code can you show us that's controlling the transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problems is within XSLTC, so you may want to [read through some of the documentation](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc_usage.html).

Comment: Thanks a ton ...I downloaded the latest jar files for XSLTC.

Comment: link is broken, can you drop some light here?